# Making packages with metapackage dependencies

Tags: ros, catkin-make, gazebo-ros-control, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the Gazebo ROS control [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control#Createaros_controlspackage) and the following command is creating issues for me.

> catkin_create_pkg MYROBOT_control ros_control ros_controllers

I understand that ros_control and ros_controllers are metapackages, but how can I make a the necessary control package that depends on the packages in the dependencies?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266087/making-packages-with-metapackage-dependencies./) by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**UPDATE**

> I want to know how I can add the necessary dependencies if I can't use the metapackages as dependencies as listed in the tutorial.

Looking at the tutorial you referred to, IMO your question is valid. I've [suggested](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-requests/438/both-ros_control-and-ros_controllers-are/diff) a possible fix. You must pass explicit dependencies.

---

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but if you're asking if it's possible for your_package to depend on `metapackage`s, <s>yes, and your_package can include all direct dependency defined in a metapackage as well as transitive ones</s> **no** normal catkin package cannot depend on metapackages (ref. [REP-0127](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#metapackage)).

Only metapackages can depend on other metapackages.
E.g. `ros-kinetic-desktop-full`, which is a metapackage that [includes standard packages](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html#desktop-variants), depends on [another metapackage ros-kinetic-desktop](https://github.com/ros/metapackages/blob/d56a5d422d02300ce6ce3cc50846053f9195bcd6/desktop_full/package.xml#L13), which [depends on another metapackages](https://github.com/ros/metapackages/blob/d56a5d422d02300ce6ce3cc50846053f9195bcd6/desktop/package.xml#L16_L20).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-07-11**:
When I run catkin_make after running the command listed above, it fails with an error saying "metapackages cannot be used as dependencies"

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-07-11**:
My bad. I've updated my answer. Btw as I mentioned I still don't know what you were asking.

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-07-11**:
I want to know how I can add the necessary dependencies if I can't use the metapackages as dependencies as listed in the tutorial.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-01-13**:
@tjvt That sounds like a requirement for a Catkin package to be a Catkin metapackage, without having to do dependency. No?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-13**:
What @tjvt adds in his comment is indeed a required `export` for metapackages. Without that `export`, the package will not be a metapackage.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-13**:
I'm not entirely sure what you're writing here, but two comments:

- don't depend on metapackages from regular packages. Depend on the actual dependencies instead (ie: don't depend on transitive dependencies, metapackages can (and will) change)
- metapackages don't get built